# Bootstrap nesting columns making vertical gap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, nested

I have a problem with bootstrap nesting cols - there is a vertical gap when one content is longer. You can see it here:

http://techbrainers.com/newtechbr/category/clubrd/?lang=en

I can't set fixed height for this colls. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hi, are you talking about the group of six blocks? I notice that if you resize or navigate away from the page and come back the bottom two blocks are no longer side by side. It seems that the 6th block can no longer fit. Is this the area with the vertical gap above?

Comment: Yes, I am talking exactly about this group of six blocks. 6th block can no longer fit. But, if for ex. 3rd block woud contain 2-line title inside and would be higher. than 4th block would be also below, not next to 3rd...

Comment: As it look now each has the same length of content. With your css class do you have a set max-height for each of these divs?

Comment: I just noticed that the text in each block is not contained and it flows out of the block to the right.

Comment: Ok, I see what is happening now. When I first load this page all lines up ok. And the text flows to the right out of each block, but when this happens all blocks are the same height. But after resize or nav away and back each of your text area are contained and then the blocks have different heights. Try to contain the text and try to get a height that will suit all blocks and set the to a fixed height (same height for all) so one block doesn't push another down like they do now.

Comment: Give fixed height for `class="RDarticle"` and on the 4th line you can apply `text-overflow:ellipsis` . Try it...